# How can I get around: "query did not return a unique result"

Tags: grails, groovy

How can I get around this error message?

> query did not return a unique result

Which is being produced from this code:

```
try {
    crnResults = CRN.where {time == timeParam}.get()
} catch (Exception ex) {
    flash.message = ex.message + " -- err: 717"
}
```

Answer (score 6):

If your query has the possibility to return more than one result then you should use `.list()` instead of `.get()`.

To get only one result from you query with some sort rule, use this:

`crnResults = CRN.where { time == timeParam }.list(max: 1, sort: "id", order: "desc")`

Otherwise, just use `.list()`.